# Issue with tab size on console applications

Tags: linux, text-editors, neovim

I am having issues with tab size on vim, neovim and nano on both terminals I have (st and alacritty).
On terminal text editors tabs are 8 spaces long, but if I open the same file with either sublime text, Clion or Eclipse I see the same tab as 4 spaces(which is desired).
Only exception I found is in lua files, where tab size is 2 for all editors except nano.

LunarVim is an outlier where tab size is always 2.

If I create a file on NeoVim(not in regular Vim) then when file is saved indentation changes to 2 spaces for all editors.(Edit: Forgot I had an autocmd for this on neovim)

What do I do to make it consistent? Is it possible to make it always 4 spaces?

Comment: Tab spacing is program independent - I'm of the mindset tabs should always be converted to spaces, as it makes for much better compatibility between programs. `vim`, `nano`, GUI text editors, etc. will all have a config setting to auto convert all tabs to spaces, which would resolve the display inconsistencies. All also have config options to set how many spaces a tab should be, and with code, four or eight is waaaay too many, resulting in an inefficient display of the code, and a ton of wasted space. If working on random machines, create terminal configs on GitHub to download and use =]

Comment: These are the custom configs I use for `nano` _([`.nanorc`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts+Configs/Nano/.nanorc))_ and `vim` _([`.vimrc`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Vim/.vimrc))_

Comment: 8 spaces for sure are too many, but I like 4, not too sure if it is good on my 15" laptop, but on my 27" monitor it's great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal tabs are "always" 8 characters (positions) wide, I'd call this "hardware tabs", as it stems from the default tab stops of the typewriter ages.

"More advanced Text editors" usually have two settings; use simulated hardware tabs, or use space-fill techniques to define shorter tab-locations.
What exactly to use can often be set in "Options" or "Preferences" of that text editor.

Example; [Kate text editor](https://kate-editor.org/) > Menu:Settings > Configure Kate > Dialog:Editing > /Indentation\ > Indent using spaces > ...

Example; [nano](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nano), terminal text editor has the command line options -T, -E and -i options to define what to use and how wide tab stops should be and whether to "autoindent" (copy the whitespace from the line above the current). Ref: `$ man nano`

So, your "problem" editors (sublime text, Clion, Eclipse) are likely to have **settings** (preferences) that define their differing behavior.

*`C:\> type file.txt` or `$ cat file.txt` is most likely to "always" expand TAB-characters (in the file) to 8 positions.*
*Ref: `$ man terminfo` hit <kbd>/</kbd>, type `Tabs and Initialization`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>*

Oh? Not using Linux, sorry - you didn't tell!

Comment: 'Terminal tabs are "always" 8 characters (positions) wide' -- What is the purpose of `tabs` command then? It seems at least some terminals can/could be configured.

Comment: `man tabs` "This uses the **terminfo** clear_all_tabs and set_tab capabilities." - you knew about this command? Would you wager that "the common user" has the same knowledge? How likely is it that e.g. `nano` uses this terminfo capability?